# How to install Movitz

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Does anyone know how to install Movitz? I could not figure it out, even after going through several web pages, and downloading various files. Is there a file that I can download to install Movitz, or must I create it myself?

Comment: There are instructions in the trac wiki

Answer (score 0):

The trac wiki has the [instructions](https://trac.common-lisp.net/movitz/wiki/FromNothingToImage)

```
(require 'movitz) ;; Or (ql:quickload movitz)
(create-image)
(movitz:dump-image :path "foo.img")
```

the on the shell run

```
qemu -fda foo.img -boot a
```

However since the project was written, bordeaux-threads added the nicknames bt, which conflicts with binary-types. [My fork](https://github.com/PuercoPop/Movitz) fixes that issue, and that issue only.

There is also [Csziacobus's  fork](https://github.com/csziacobus/movitz) which adds an image viewer using McCLIM which I would recommend as a starting point.